# Approaches to high dimension pattern matching problem

Tags: r

My apologies in advance as I am new to this. I have searched the internet and tried various processes and nothing seems to work or address this situation.

I have a dataset of 30,000 transactions and 500,000 items. Average item size for a transaction is 50. The dataset is sparse, so the support number must be set quite low. Furthermore, the rules become more valuable the larger the number of items in the rule.

I have tried running this in arules and the tests fail after exceeding 64 gb of RAM (the limit of the machine). I have tried reducing items and transactions to smaller subsets, but still hit this memory limit.

Ultimately, I am looking for ways to cluster large groups of similar accounts by selection of items and generate confidence and lift of various next items selected from those clusters.

My question: are there alternative, more efficient ways to do this, or other approaches to consider?

Thank you.

Comment: I flagged this question for migration to Data Science SE site, as I think it's not a statistics question, but a data mining (data science) one.

Comment: You can consider to disk based processing instead of whole in memory approach. Just read a batch of instances that fit in your memory update your clusters then read another batch from disk and go on like this. This is slow but the most realiable way. You can conside to use HDF5 like data structures as well, to read structured data from disk.

Answer (score 1):

According to the following discussion on *StackOverflow*, a situation like that you've described can occur, when one of the variables in a data set is of **unexpected type** (for example, a `factor` instead of a `character`): https://stackoverflow.com/q/7246412/2872891.

Also, consider using package `bigmemory`, recommended in the accepted answer, or similar packages for *big data* analysis. For the latter, please see section **"Large memory and out-of-memory data"** in *CRAN Task View* [High-Performance and Parallel Computing with R](http://cran.r-project.org/web/views/HighPerformanceComputing.html).

Finally, an additional note. There is an **ecosystem** of R packages, built around the `arules` package, which includes supporting packages for algorithms (`arulesNBMiner`), applications (`arulesSequences`, `arulesClassify`) and visualization (`arulesViz`). You are likely aware of [that](http://www.jmlr.org/papers/volume12/hahsler11a/hahsler11a.pdf), but I have decided to include this good-to-know fact just in case and for the sake of completeness.

Comment: Thank you Aleksandr. I didn't consider it, but there are factors instead of characters in the data set. I will coerce as character and run again!

Comment: @Chris: My pleasure, Chris! Would love to hear about the results. Don't forget to accept/upvote, if my answer is helpful :-).